# Rundeck Failed: NonZeroResultCode: Remote command failed with exit status -1 Timeout

Tags: rundeck

i have a problem with my rundeck, in automatisation process i need to perform some long task with Rundeck such as Database Refresh from PRODUCTION to TEST Database.

This case cause problems sometimes.

I've no timeout set on rundeck job, i use script that launch action on a distant server trough SSH.

If a step took long time (Drop database, import database with datapump), Rundeck generate an error

> Failed: NonZeroResultCode: Remote command failed with exit status -1

after a certain period of time.

It's look like a timeout, but i don't know where this timeout occured and i can't find it.

But the DROP or the IMPDB still continue his job and if you wait for it, the action has successfully completed but rundeck marked the step as failed, i put some workaround such as error handler to by pass but it's not very clean.

Do you have any idea were that timeout is set ?

In my opininon, after a certain period of time, if rundeck did not receive an answer from the distant server, it cut off and mark as failed with the error code Failed: NonZeroResultCode: Remote command failed with exit status -1

Comment: Could you share the log output in debug mode?

Answer (score 0):

You can increase the ssh timeout globally at the `framework.properties` file.

Stop the Rundeck server, then add the following lines on the `/etc/rundeck/framework.properties` file:

```
framework.ssh-connection-timeout=0
framework.ssh-command-timeout=0
```

Then start the Rundeck service.

The timeout values are in milliseconds, 0 is indefinite.

More info [here](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/projects/node-execution/ssh.html#specifying-ssh-timeout-options).